# REST request to particular server or IP

Tags: web-services, urllib

I am currently using Web service to fetch data.using python urllib2 library. 
In which can i send request to particular server? instead of web service choosing the server?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first example here:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.. have you seen this page: http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-python.html?m=1  ?